# Are the any self reproducing robots?

Tags: manufacturing

Is there a possibility of making robots which utilise  raw materials to create more versions of themselves? Clarifying the point what I would like to ask is that whether there are are any projects or research on robots that can reproduce!!!

Comment: Ever heard of the reprap project?

Comment: Umm no could send me the site

Comment: The reprap 3d printers are an open source/open hardware project where a good majority of the parts can be printed to create a new reprap 3d printer.  It's not 100% self replicating, because repraps can't print a nozzle or any of the metal parts / electronic parts, much less assemble the parts together.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* user39460, but I'm afraid that speculative questions like this really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works. Also, the [*Robotics* question checklist](http://meta.robotics.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) has good advice on how to write a good question.

Comment: I am sorry but essentially I wanted some information  about whether there is any existence of robots that can reproduce like smaller versions of themselves or actually can survive without human interaction or interference!! So my question is not actually broad but presice on asking whether there are any robots that can reproduce!!

Comment: If that is the crux of your question then the answer is a definite no.  People will cite reprap, or nano replicating sites, and claim self-replication.  The reality is that going from raw materials, to the state in which specific robot construction or replication can take place, requires an enormous amount of processing that is generally unaccounted for by the claims of self-replication.   As a simple example, consider how a spool of ABS plastic is created in order to manufacture a single 3D printed part.   No part of the reprap project creates the spool of material from raw materials.

Comment: Sorry @user39460 even specifying it to be current research projects doesn't make it a good fit for a stack exchange site. Any answers that you might get would soon be out of date, so a simple google search would almost always be more useful than answers on this question. If you wish to discuss this more, feel free to bring it up in [chat] when you have a [reputation of 20](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat).